# Re rendering a page after the component is mounted?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Sorry if the title wasn't super descriptive. I used all my leftover brain power trying to solve my problem...

My route for user profiles looks like this: `/profile/:username`

When a user visits that page, I have a `componentDidMount` lifecycle method fire to get the profile information and the render that information on the screen.

The problem comes when a user is on the profile page and then searches for another user. Since they stay on the profile page, the component never re-mounts. Thus not re-pulling the new users data, which in return doesn't change state... which equals no new data on screen.

I have tried many different ways to go around this issue.

One way I attempted was refactoring the method to grab the user data into its own method. Then I would call that method when I receive new props. Since the method `componentWillReceiveProps` is now deprecated, I tried using `getDerivedStateFromProps` to no avail.

How should I go about solving this problem.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: I recommend using a state management tool like redux. 

Essentially - the user data should be stored in the redux state. That data is then connected into the react component props via `mapStateToProps` In the componentDidMount (and componentDidUpdate) methods, you check if the data exists. If it doesn't exist, you fire an action to fetch it.

Comment: why should people use redux for simple problems like this one.

Comment: Have your current user information rendered from Component state, then update state with the searched user information when the user performs a search for another user's profile

Comment: all you need is have a state data for the new user data, when you get the search data update the state, then the component will re-render.

Comment: use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) - classic solution